# JQuery update stored object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-flipster

I'm using JQuery Flipster(https://github.com/drien/jquery-flipster) and I'm trying to get a modal window to pop-up only for the `current item` that's at the front. I've used an alert below just for testing purposes.

I can get the action to happen by doing this:

```
$('.flipster__item--current').click(function(){
        alert('Testing!');
    });
```

Problem I'm having is that the `.flipster_item--current` stays only on the first object with that class when the page loads, even after the class gets applied to other objects in the carousel.

I figured out Flipster has an option for a callback after the carousel moves below but can't crack how to set it so it updates the `--current` each time the carousel moves and also removes `--current` from the previous item.

Flipster Option below:

```
onItemSwitch: false
    // [function]
    // Callback function when items are switched
    // Arguments received: [currentItem, previousItem]
```

Really appreciate anyone's time for this problem.

I tried this code below as well:

```
// the flipster element on your page
        $("#coverflow").flipster({
         onItemSwitch: myHandler
            //Arguments received: [currentItem, previousItem]
        });
        //your handler
        function myHandler(currentItem, previousItem) {
            $(previousItem).removeClass("flipster__item--current");
            $(currentItem).click(function(){
                alert('Testing!');
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Adding your handler. You can access details of the current object by wrapping it with jquery  `$(current)`

```
$(function () {
    // the flipster element on your page
    $("#coverflow").flipster({
        style : 'carousel',
        onItemSwitch : myHandler
        //Arguments received: [currentItem, previousItem]
    });
    //your handler
    function myHandler(current, prev) {
        alert('Testing!');
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @searching This is still giving me the same functionality though.  I added trying using the `removeClass`  option but still nothing. `// the flipster element on your page.  I edited question to show code. 
     Any thoughts?

Comment: @dgreen22 NP. May be I understood the problem wrong. Why is that that you remove the class if you want to show the modal when they click the item in front?  Should it first select and then allow them to click or...??

Comment: I was seeing if that would help as what's happening is when any item moves away from the front `current` position, even when you click on it then, it still shows the popup, meaning it still associates the `current` class with any item that was in the front position at any point and isn't removing it so only one item has the `current` class at any given moment.  So I was thinking I could remove that class so the `current` class would only be applied to the front facing one. Hope that makes sense.  Please let me know if you have thoughts.